# sonar-scanner command not found in mac

Tags: sonarqube, sonarscanner

i followed the directions as per the SonarQube documentation.  I installed the sonarqube and sonar-scanner from the instructions into my applications folder.  But having trouble getting my terminal to recognize sonar-scanner.  I checked my path variable by trying the following:

```
echo $PATH
```

and got...

/Users/Neptune/Applications/SonarQube/bin:/Users/Neptune/Applications/SonarScanner/bin:/Users/Neptune/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/domino:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

This is what i have for my path

```
export PATH="/Users/Neptune/Applications/SonarScanner/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/Neptune/Applications/SonarQube/bin:$PATH"
```

I then changed it to:

```
export PATH="/Users/Neptune/Applications/SonarScanner/bin/sonar-scanner:$PATH"
```

AFter each method, i restarted my shell and still no luck.  I then went to my project root directory where i have my python code installed and added a project.properties file but i don't see how that helps with the terminal recognizing sonar-scanner -h as a command.  Can someone please help.  Thanks

SonarQube fires for me and im able to start a localhost:9000 server.  Its getting mac to recognize sonar-scanner is whats causing me problems.

edit: i managed to get sonar-scanner working.  But it's such a painful process.  I have to always type:

```
sh /Applications/SonarScanner/bin/sonar-scanner
```

Comment: Check for the user permissions to execute sonar scanner

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same issue:

> zsh: command not found: sonar-scanner

I have installed sonar globally

```
npm install sonarqube-scanner -g
```

And it worked for me.